# Why does the result of FPeval disappear after a `&`

Tags: tables, fp

I am trying to use the `fp` package, and the results are deeply confusing to me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
\FPeval\testing{2 + 2}
a & \testing
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This will not compile:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mvce.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty))
No file mvce.aux.
( FP-EVAL ( FP-UPN ( FP-ADD ) ) )
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 a & \testing
```

However, removing the `&` will give the intended result. *Why does that happen, and what can I do about it? Should I use a different package for arithmetic?*

This is just a simplified example. I actually want to use the result multiple times across a `&` and `\\` boundary, which is why I can't just move the `FPeval` where the result is used.

Answer (score 7):

`\testing` is a local variable, lost in the local scope (corresponding to each cell of the `tabular`).  You need to set it global to use it in a different cell, or outside the `tabular`.

EDIT: Since egreg strongly recommends avoiding the syntax `\global\let\testing\testing`, I instead introduce `\localtesting` and `\testing` as the local and global versions of the same data.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
\FPeval\localtesting{2 + 2}\global\let\testing\localtesting
a & \testing
\end{tabular}

Look, I am even available outside the tabular: \testing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it more the cells than the tabular env? Each cell in a table is a local group.

Comment: I believe that's what I need, thanks. Are there any other scopes than `\global`? For example, is it possible to make the variable's scope be the interior of a `\newcommand` definition? Could I wrap this construction into a macro, to avoid typing it out every time? Something like `\myeval\global\testing{2 + 2}`

Comment: @daleif That is what I meant, but I see how it can be confused...I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @NieDzejkob There are only local and global scopes.  With extra work, you could save a global variable, change it as you wish, and then reset it back to the earlier value, but why spend the effort?  That said, you could certainly define a `\gFPeval` that accomplishes both the `\FPeval` and the globalization.

Comment: To wrap this monstrosity into a neat macro: `\def\geval#1#2{\FPeval#1{#2}\global\let#1#1}`

Comment: Things like `\global\let\x=\x` should be avoided.

Comment: @egreg I thought you were going to say that...